# Why would SiteNavigationElement have a schema attribute of "material"?

Tags: schema.org

Can someone kindly help me understand Schema.org? For example, this page lists the schema for site navigation:

http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement

But why is `material` an attribute? Why or when would `material` be listed?

My understanding of these schema attributes is that they describe the element which it contains. So why would a navigation element need to have `material` such as leather or plastic? Or is my understanding of these schema attributes wrong?

Comment: any suggestions on a forum where I can go to get interaction and discussion on schema and structured data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Schema.org type can always have all properties of its parent types.

Not all properties necessarily make sense for all children types.

---

For [`SiteNavigationElement`](http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement), the parent type is `WebPageElement`, and its parent type is `CreativeWork`, and its parent type is `Thing`.

The [`material`](http://schema.org/material) property is defined for `CreativeWork` (and `Product`). A `CreativeWork` can also be a physical work, for which it can make sense to specify the `material`. If you have a digital `CreativeWork` (like every `SiteNavigationElement` would be), simply ignore this property.